# If 3 divides $n+m$,show that $F_{n-m-1}F_n+F_{n-m}F_{n+1}$ is an even integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

> If $3$ divides $n+m$,show that $F_{n-m-1}F_n+F_{n-m}F_{n+1}$ is an even
>   integer

I've no idea of initiating  this.Please provide some hint

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) tells us that
$$
 F_{m} F_{n+1} + F_{m-1} F_n = F_{m+n}
$$
which I shall rewrite as
$$
 F_{a-1} F_b + F_{a} F_{b+1} = F_{a+b}
$$
Therefore, with $a=n-m$ and $b=n$, we get
$$
F_{n-m-1}F_n+F_{n-m}F_{n+1} = F_{n-m+n} = F_{2n-m}
$$
On the other hand,
$F_n$ is even iff $n$ is a multiple of $3$, because the Fibonacci sequence mod $2$ is $0,1,1,0,1,1,0,\dots$ (starting at index $0$).

Therefore,
$F_{n-m-1}F_n+F_{n-m}F_{n+1} = F_{n-m+n} = F_{2n-m}$ is even iff $2n-m$ is a multiple of $3$, which is equivalent to $n+m$ is a multiple of $3$, since $n+m=(3n)-(2n-m)$.

Comment: :sequence should be $1,1,0,1,1,0,....$

Comment: @PKStyles, the Fibonacci sequence usually starts at $F_0=0$. But it makes no difference to the argument.

Comment: Nice. I guess that as long as the recurrence you're looking at is of the form "$F_n =$ a polynomial in $F_{n-1},\ldots,F_0$" this kind of thinking is going to be applicable. It's obviously very powerful.